# Shares from mining Electroneum sent to my Electroneum wallet never show up?

Tags: transactions

I've been mining Electroneum for a few days, primarily to learn about how Electroneum works.  It uses the CryptoNight algorithm, similar to Monero, which means CPU/GPU mining is not impossibly ineffective, as it is with SHA256 algorithms.

Anyway, I'm running a "full" Electroneum node using the Windows x64 binary from their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/electroneum/electroneum/releases).  The node is completely synced with electroneumd.exe running 24x7, and has been since well prior to my mining attempts.  I've also configured a new wallet using their electroneum-wallet-cli.exe utility.

The wallet public address is:

```
etnjzALa1ALdXZg7WtVFUyLcpXHaQ3apbKg8oe3Su3sbafpdReqtcHv7THqjemDsYL6wbwc7euM9JbAkRvrLFScu5cywxpZryW
```

You can see the mining progress at [EasyHash.io](https://easyhash.io/stats/etnjzALa1ALdXZg7WtVFUyLcpXHaQ3apbKg8oe3Su3sbafpdReqtcHv7THqjemDsYL6wbwc7euM9JbAkRvrLFScu5cywxpZryW).

Since I've mined over 10 ETN with EasyHash, they made a payment to my wallet yesterday:

[image]

Since one of the principal tenets of Electroneum is "fast transaction speeds", I expected my full-node wallet to show a balance quite quickly after the transaction was confirmed.  I can see the transaction has been confirmed by looking at [blockexplorer.electroneum.com  for the transaction details](https://blockexplorer.electroneum.com/search?value=722bbdb5a3c027ab9ebc55e5b5d0e7ef13ba6196fcdbe66b2aeb0ad32abdb648).  That block explorer page allows you to provide a wallet id, and the private view key for that wallet, to see if there are any transaction outputs in the transaction that apply to the given wallet.  Doing that shows two outputs for my wallet:

[image]

Private view key:

```
e98d706e4a62a83d959c6df570bf65e24ee0308537c97bed451d89ee6dc7aa03
```

My full-node sees the relevant block:

```
print_block 87959
timestamp: 1514502042
previous hash: b707f9935c434195496d5d1e377cec8c2cbabbaa3827de6e52ba470eedff5fd8
nonce: 13982434
is orphan: 0
height: 87959
depth: 970
hash: 751c2f32b076ce3f3478e5bda248918294608d86092d217b018aba30e04984f8
difficulty: 12813644700
reward: 735238
{
  "major_version": 1,
  "minor_version": 1,
  "timestamp": 1514502042,
  "prev_id": "b707f9935c434195496d5d1e377cec8c2cbabbaa3827de6e52ba470eedff5fd8",
  "nonce": 13982434,
  "miner_tx": {
    "version": 1,
    "unlock_time": 87977,
    "vin": [ {
        "gen": {
          "height": 87959
        }
      }
    ],
    "vout": [ {
        "amount": 8,
        "target": {
          "key": "8742856f2490c3eb0c196400068ed2cb04d8a75d7bb8bf5fa6ea9eb108a86641"
        }
      }, {
        "amount": 30,
        "target": {
          "key": "16ab5846579152d99421fbd6797f30b94f34e8c706c122df83ccb718d4c46769"
        }
      }, {
        "amount": 200,
        "target": {
          "key": "77fa7185ee41f40231008de56cbb363287c5cff5c806177a2157288d7eeaf209"
        }
      }, {
        "amount": 5000,
        "target": {
          "key": "c22b4814deea2e48803794c184e367347fef5a94404ae4c21b5c446ca5b063b8"
        }
      }, {
        "amount": 30000,
        "target": {
          "key": "9f2ad815c02e733837c4be152b22b7fa592d7c7138134e52b594964b8f3548e9"
        }
      }, {
        "amount": 700000,
        "target": {
          "key": "59f325a51da3240f411f72b8a90d291d0a558b9afab6b6c3f6b59b0d1aa09935"
        }
      }
    ],
    "extra": [ 1, 84, 24, 31, 2, 222, 95, 37, 14, 36, 206, 200, 190, 184, 156, 31, 74, 204, 199, 246, 95, 31, 180, 239, 2, 86, 0, 89, 146, 168, 240, 1
89, 26, 2, 8, 0, 10, 8, 0, 28, 82, 253, 252
    ],
    "signatures": [ ]
  },
  "tx_hashes": [ "f4f18c1dcc02c8f86b2a6486499e346474e4cd55ca845a265ea88ec684cdf46a", "04a91cac8513e769c8eba4a082958672bae7a511ddaf1c926af5b03945eb1cec
", "626cd3ba9212dd6e600e6f0f33973941c640c618538a8836abf8084125be102f", "abfb6818d4908fa5d2a437b69bc086706f9b567e619b3e39d791ffb87b08a3ad", "e8b2d7119f
46da5f9bbcf9082593035e1d4e638f4a3b487992cc5631529ef909", "722bbdb5a3c027ab9ebc55e5b5d0e7ef13ba6196fcdbe66b2aeb0ad32abdb648", "800d3fba5c393c57e2203485
d73a5e4b58fecf284856a41bccc71d3f089ecf24", "bcc9ff42774d5599b4dfe87cf72baa61a300d8158e2210752f951c86d0064ecf", "8aa3a541daa9081f57499d90af7226162dc8a3
9f403e417b30260854d40567d5", "cf6a5705361d42980a9564b6fbb105172b716b477432ccedaedbe91226ee289b", "1978c8e0f05e653e3ebc2988ef961cf0cdf5522f73d1aa4f4fa0
e066ac45512c", "6e663cdf3c206c3c23215f3d5cd2adf6b35ac6e26df1e464e0f418fa6d9dc31e", "87dd6cad09b7c34a6369aa555925377d75480139534399c0403fc457d7a7c9d3",
 "87bea19d60de8255055e6d587431e0651fb2a936f94c94996c08bcc873227dcd", "f60b08afdb2d9206bc7fb38d5905be396c0b22d4f0e9d3fcd610ca75db16d23f"
  ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  Surely my wallet should show a balance of 13 ETN ?

FYI, this is also being discussed on [the Electroneum subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Electroneum/comments/7oty1q/warning_electroneum_forked_from_unstable_monero/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this question from Reddit, decided to take a look and the Electroneum is showing up for me

```
Generated new wallet: etnjzALa1ALdXZg7WtVFUyLcpXHaQ3apbKg8oe3Su3sbafpdReqtcHv7THqjemDsYL6wbwc7euM9JbAkRvrLFScu5cywxpZryW
Restore from specific blockchain height (optional, default 0),
or alternatively from specific date (YYYY-MM-DD): 0
Starting refresh...
Height 87959, transaction <722bbdb5a3c027ab9ebc55e5b5d0e7ef13ba6196fcdbe66b2aeb0ad32abdb648>, received 10.00
Height 87959, transaction <722bbdb5a3c027ab9ebc55e5b5d0e7ef13ba6196fcdbe66b2aeb0ad32abdb648>, received 3.00
Height 89320, transaction <c69cbada5ed5a37ef541fe0a863126cb1d3e08b055713947e1ff518d771c1ba8>, received 10.00
Height 89559, transaction <f808c7e31a76c39d7f340554338784e87553c0d596181f517d7b3bee83206a49>, received 10.00
Height 89861, transaction <47fe6db8776ba5c5ef70e985cd867a869e7037623b76821f14a9a31ff59d1047>, received 10.00
Height 89861, transaction <47fe6db8776ba5c5ef70e985cd867a869e7037623b76821f14a9a31ff59d1047>, received 1.00
Height 90361, transaction <13cd1c4fae0007859f759402791107f8b48cf340fbef92b391abfb773c6511b1>, received 3.00
Height 90361, transaction <13cd1c4fae0007859f759402791107f8b48cf340fbef92b391abfb773c6511b1>, received 10.00
Height 91099, transaction <5cc9ad6ee647544792776912b54a00ec28cc7d9625df8f853cb823bf0bf5e2f0>, received 20.00
Height 91879, transaction <7a0b69ee2b5855dbea3e6a231b3559faba86412a3a7880e7fa1695e0e79eacba>, received 10.00
Height 92202, transaction <ef5d3c1d81227beb461e88911a660379988c3d8e75768752a7d55dc7fba39a93>, received 1.00
Height 101724, transaction <1f8ab5436005cd390ceec38ecfc69bcac536895a8fe16e1b012ad1a8fde448fa>, received 0.02
Height 101724, transaction <1f8ab5436005cd390ceec38ecfc69bcac536895a8fe16e1b012ad1a8fde448fa>, received 0.10
Refresh done, blocks received: 105108                           
Balance: 88.12, unlocked balance: 88.12
```

So everything seems to be there from my side.

Try recreating the wallet with `electroneum-wallet-cli.exe -generate-from-keys` using the same address, private spend key, and private view key.  Obviously, make sure you backup the original wallet.dat to ensure you have access to the correct keys.

Comment: I used the macOS version. 
I also used a public daemon instead of a local one.

Comment: see... the devil is in the details.  This question is about "running a full Electroneum node using the Windows x64 binary from their GitHub repo."  - I appreciate your help, and the link to the reddit question.

Comment: "electroneum-wallet-cli.exe --generate-from-view-key stack" "Balance: 88.12, unlocked balance: 88.12". Exact same result on windows while running a full active node on windows. Maybe try generating a new wallet from keys through the cli?

Comment: Thanks for checking.  I've deleted the entire blockchain from my node and have restarted the node.  It's now re-downloading the entire blockchain from other nodes.  Once that completes, I will re-create the wallet.  Did you start your node with the ["raw" blockchain provided in their Github repository](https://github.com/electroneum/electroneum/releases), or did it download blocks from other nodes?  Also, have a +1

Comment: I downloaded it from other nodes, it was faster than importing the raw blockchain.

Comment: weird.  I just re-created the wallet from the address, private spend key, and private view key, and now it sees the transactions.  Perhaps there was a problem with the blockchain or something.  I did rescan_bc many times, and never saw any transactions previously.

Comment: the original address, private view key and private spend key were generated by the electroneum-wallet-cli.exe - the same one I'm using now.